# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904 - "ID": invalid identifier

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I want to map a table to a Entity -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBSCRIPTIONFILE", schema = "SUBSCRIPTIONSERVICES")
public class SUBSCRIPTIONFILE {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String PRODUCTSKU;
    private String VERSION;
    private String PLATFORM;
    private String FILENAME;
    private String DESCRIPTION;

    protected SUBSCRIPTIONFILE() {
    };
    //setter & getters
```

And I get -  `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "SUBSCRIPTI0_"."ID": invalid identifier` so I removed the ID field and get -

```
`No identifier specified for entity:` `com.siemens.plm.it.aws.connect.entitys.SUBSCRIPTIONFILE`
```

I had copy-paste all the Table, Scheme and fields name, and tried to remove @Table and or any other SO answer I saw but still could not solved it.
After removing `@Entity` -

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.siemens.plm.it.aws.connect.entitys.SUBSCRIPTIONFILE`, removing `@Table` -

`No identifier specified for entity: com.siemens.plm.it.aws.connect.entitys.SUBSCRIPTIONFILE`.

------------Scheme------------

[image]

Comment: Could you please attach the table schema?

Comment: Yes, adding to question.

Comment: You should explicitly specify the `ID` column of `numeric` type in the table. 
Please also make sure it's not a case-sensitivity issue

Comment: 1 - you don't have to have a ID column. 2 - I posted the scheme and all names are upper.

Comment: Yes it works if I set another colunm to be my ID.

Comment: You dont say if your JPA provider CREATED the table or not. If not then hardly surprising since you dont have a column called ID yet your mapping says you need one. If the table is existing then tell us what is the PK column, and what is its column definition.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your entity class looks ok except id field.

Try by changing variable name from "id" to "myId" or any name which is not a oracle database keyword.

Comment: No, still the same error with new name - `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "SUBSCRIPTI0_"."PKSUID": invalid identifier`.